# How to restore root access to a broken Amazon EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, console

What if SSH (or maybe even all TCP) access to a EC2 instance is lost?

How to restore root access in this case?

Is there a Linux console in EC2 (provided it runs Linux) similar to console in Digital Ocean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should review the troubleshooting steps [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-linux-ssh-troubleshooting/) to target common connectivity issues. If that doesn't work you can try to do the following:

- Start a new Linux instance
- Stop the instance you are having trouble with
- Detach the root volume of the broken instance
- Attach the root volume of the broken instance to the new instance as an additional disk
- Mount the additional disk and try to troubleshoot what may be wrong.

  - You can look at the user's `authorized_keys` file (`/home/<user>/.ssh/authorized_keys`) and verify it matches a working instance's authorized keys in the same location (should contain the public id of your AWS key pair).
  - Review log files for other possible issues
- Attempt to fix the issue or recover the data you need to spin up a new instance
- Shutdown down the new instance and detach the volume if you believe you fixed the issue
- Attach the volume to the old instance
- Try to launch again